# Why does the debugging statement in main not produce the same result as the debugging statements in each of the subfunctions?

Tags: c, pointers

Why does the debugging print statement in main not produce the same result as the debugging print statements in each of the subfunctions?  The debugging statements are not indented.  Thanks!

CODE:

```
//function declarations
void    getData (char vehicleType);
void    getVType (char* vehicleType);
int main()
{
//local declarations
    char    vehicleType;                //type of vehicle    - user input

//statements
    getData (vehicleType);
printf("\nin main vehicleType: %c\n", vehicleType);

    return 0;
}

void    getData (char vehicleType)
{
    getVType(&vehicleType);
printf("\nin getData vehicleType: %c\n", vehicleType);
}

void    getVType(char* vehicleType)
{
    printf("vehicle type: ");
    scanf("%c", vehicleType);
printf("\nin getVType, you entered: %c\n", *vehicleType);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
vehicle type: c

in getVType, you entered: c

in getData vehicleType: c

in main vehicleType:

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 1.949 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main` `vehicleType` is never set so it's value is undefined. The others work because you're passing by reference (pointer), not value.

To get the value back to main, you need to either return it

```
c = getData();

char    getData ()
{
    char vehicleType
    getVType(&vehicleType);
    printf("\nin getData vehicleType: %c\n", *vehicleType);
    return vehicleType;
}
```

Or pass by reference

```
getData(&c);

void    getData (char *vehicleType)
{
    getVType(vehicleType);
    printf("\nin getData vehicleType: %c\n", *vehicleType);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so if I'm getting the value from `getVType` how then does it get assigned inside of `main` so I can use it in other (not posted) functions?

What would make it print the 'c' in main is basically what I'm asking?  I'd try to word it better if my knowledge of pointers was less hazy.

Comment: The `vehicleType` that `getData()` uses is a copy of the `c` in `main`. They are not the same value. The `vehicleType` passed to `getVType` is the address of the `vehicleType` in `getData()`, so those two functions are using the same value. If you want it to get back into main, you need to use the same `pass by reference` calls (i.e. use a pointer) as you've got between `getData` and `getVType`

Comment: Ok, I get what you're saying, but when I do that I get something to the effect of `error: invalid type (char**)` because I use the same process when I get down to the `getVType` subfunction.  Where is the proper place to make the address `&` reference when dealing with multiple subfunctions?  ...So that it doesn't compound (pointer to pointer)....

And thanks so much!

Comment: Once you have a pointer you don't need to do it again - it is literally pointing to the thing you want to modify. See edits above.

Comment: I see what you did there in the `pass by reference` block... so, in `getVType` do I just use `vehicleType` as a regular variable or as a pointer?  Do I just leave it as is?  I hope that makes sense... I'm just trying to wrap my brain around it.

Comment: `getVType` doesn't change at all. The only difference is when you call it you've already got a pointer, so you don't need the `&` anymore.

Comment: Ok, I think it's clear now.  Thanks, John.  Much obliged.

Comment: If I've answered your question how about accepting my answer?

Comment: First SO question... took me a sec.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Function arguments in C are passed by value.

In `main` this call does not do what you want.

```
getData(vehicleType);
```

`getData` can change `vehicleType` all it likes within its function body. But the variable it is changing is local to that function and does not propagate back to the caller. You need to define that argument as a pointer if you want the value to be returned to the caller. Just as you do for `getVType`.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!  That clears up some of this for me, but when I started passing pointers through multiple subfunctions I started getting something like `error: invalid type (char**)` ... so, how do I avoid that?